# Is the fastest Bitcoin ASIC miner available today still profitable after block halving?

Tags: mining-profitability, mining-hardware, asic

As the title says, I was wondering if the fastest Bitcoin ASIC miner will be profitable after block halving?

Comment: Probably not at the current difficulty. We'll likely see a difficulty drop as people turn their mining hardware off, though.

Comment: If the fastest Bitcoin ASIC miner isn't profitable after halving, then the most miners have to turn their machines off right? The difficulty drop will be huge then. Will this lead to a centralization of new more efficient ASIC running by a few companies?

Comment: Whether a miner is profitable depends in large part on how much the operator pays for electricity.

Comment: 1) We don't know your business model. What's your power price? Will you be selling the miners after a period of months? 2) Be careful in assuming that the difficulty will drop. The efficiency of miners historically has increased more quickly than the reward drops. There may be a localized stall or decline in difficulty, but as far as profit calcs go, I would never assume the difficulty will drop over anything resembling the long term.

Comment: I've downvoted this question because it has an obvious answer that's useless (which is "of course, otherwise nobody would be mining anymore") and a non-obvious answer that is individual to the respective circumstances. I therefore don't find the question useful.

Answer (score 1):

The s7 miner is still a bit profitable (25% profit).
The s9 miner is the fastest and most efficiënt miner i know of and is way more proffitable of course.

edit/explaination:
Hashnest has a percentage monitor of profit/costs. Thats where the s7 number comes from. S9 is way more efficiënt following the specsheet on the antminer website. You can calc your profit over at coinwarz too, there you can edit power costs/usage and even the ROI is calculated there. Take a look i should say (its indication tho)